# SQL Joining and Update

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2016

Hope you all can help me out here.  I imported an excel file successfully into Microsoft SQL Server 2016.  I have another table so a grand total of two tables.  The field in common with both tables is a column named ProjectManager.  One table has only two columns ProjectManager, and projectNbr.  I want to join that table with another table.  ProjectManager is in both tables.  I also want to update the table that I am joining to include the column projectNbr.  One table is named dbo.Importthis, the other is named dbo.WTS_EXT_Project.  I want to be able to join both together and update the one to include projectNbr column.  Is there a command statement to accomplish this at one statement?  Alieases are ok to use.  If you all need more information or anything else let me know.  Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Instead of describing in words share the structure of your tables(schema).

Comment: So you're looking to merge two tables together and then add an additional column to the resulting table for additional information?  Or are you looking to add an additional column to one table and then keep the two tables separate but join them together for a specific query?

Comment: Im looking to add the additonal column to the resulting table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you add a column to a table. I'm assuming projectNbr is an integer:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.WTS_EXT_Project ADD COLUMN projectNbr INT
```

Then to fill your new column from the Importthis table, it would look something like this:

```
UPDATE wep
SET projectNbr = it.projectNbr
FROM dbo.WTS_EXT_Project wep
INNER JOIN dbo.Importthis it
  ON wep.ProjectManager = it.ProjectManager
```

Comment: I successfully altered my dbo.WTS_EXT_Project to have projectNbr in the table.  Now I try to run the join command and it comes back as 0 rows effected.  Can anyone tell me why please?

Comment: update [dbo].[WTS_EXT_Project]
 set projectNbr = [dbo].[Importhis].projectNbr
 from [dbo].[WTS_EXT_Project]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Importhis]
 ON [dbo].[WTS_EXT_Project].ProjectManager = 
 [dbo].[Importhis].ProjectManager

Comment: result  = 0 rows affected

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that responded to my question.  Sugergrady we were on the 10 yard line.  The Manager and Nbr needed to be flipfloped.  We got what was needed from this project at work.  So Thank you everyone.